# How to construct simple sum types in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

When you search for example sum types in Scala you get something like that:

```
sealed trait Pet
case class Cat(name: String) extends Pet
case class Fish(name: String, color: Color) extends Pet
case class Squid(name: String, age: Int) extends Pet
```

Is it possible as well to construct a sum type from simple data types like `Int` or `String`?
Something like `type simpleType = Int | String | Boolean`.

**UPDATE:**

This feature is coming with Scala 3.* and is called `Union Types`  https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html.

Comment: You can take a look at Shapeless Coproduct:
https://gist.github.com/fancellu/9a1aafd70b5c316b14f9

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/algebraic-data-types-adts-in-scala try this it may help

Comment: Scala 3 will add enums which are suitable for representing algebraic data types.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar using [VALUE CLASSES AND UNIVERSAL TRAITS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)

For example:

```
sealed trait Numbers extends Any
case class IntT(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal with Numbers
case class LongT(val underlying: Long) extends AnyVal with Numbers
```

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will try that for my use case and see how this works out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to https://github.com/frees-io/iota that supports these kind disjunctions. It needs Cats or Scalaz as dependence and allows to create types like:

```
type Foo = Cop[Int :: String :: Double :: TNil]
```